# xamarin forms BLE state unavilabe

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im trying to delvolop an xamarin forms app for both Android and ISO.

I am using this nugget pack https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

I have added this to the AndroidManiFest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

I then initiated the IBluetoothLE interface as ble

```
IBluetoothLE ble;
```

And in my constructer set it to CrossBluetoothLE.Current;

```
 ble = CrossBluetoothLE.Current;
```

When I then tried to get the state of my BLE device via writing

```
Var State = ble.state;
```

The result came out as unavailable.

What do I do?

Comment: Is you bluetooth get connected at that montent? There are examples about how to [Get the bluetooth status](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le#ibluetoothle). You can download sample and check the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to listen to state changes rather then trying to get it when it is not available at specific moment;

can place it in your ctor too

```csharp
ble.StateChanged += (s, e) => 
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"The bluetooth state changed to {e.NewState}");
};
```

You can check if the connectivity is successful by ;

again you can do it in your ctor

```js
var adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
```

then;

```js
try 
{
    await _adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device);
}
catch(DeviceConnectionException e)
{
    // ... could not connect to device
}
```